# Convert cell array of date strings (only some of which contain time) to float

Tags: string, matlab, date

I'm looking at some rather ugly code to accomplish the following:

```
function [ Y ] = timeStringToFloat( X )
    % X is a column cell-array of time-strings, e.g.:
    %
    %       4215×1 cell array
    % 
    %         '5/1/2009 3:02:00 PM'
    %         '5/1/2009 4:11:00 PM'
    %         '5/1/2009'                  <-- if time missing, assume '12:00:00 AM'
    %         '6/1/2009 12:37:00 AM'
    %         '7/1/2009 3:08:00 AM'
    %         '7/1/2009 9:30:00 PM'
    %         etc.
    % 
    % 
    %     >> Y
    % 
    %     Y =
    % 
    %        1.0e+05 *
    % 
    %        7.337786263888889
    %        7.337786743055555
    %        7.337786826388889
    %        7.337790256944444
    %        7.337801305555556
    %        7.337808958333333
    %        etc.
    %
    %
    % Convert Entry Times to date numbers, but we have to ensure that all entries contain
    % "HH:MM:SS PM" which is not the case for timestamps at 12:00:00 AM sharp.


    % For cells containing "AM" or "PM" Replace [] with 0
    IdxAM = strfind(X,'AM'); IdxAM(cellfun(@isempty,IdxAM)) = {0};
    IdxPM = strfind(X,'PM'); IdxPM(cellfun(@isempty,IdxPM)) = {0};

    % Entries without "HH:MM:SS PM" will be 0
    IdxNoTime = cell2mat(IdxAM) + cell2mat(IdxPM); 

    if min(IdxNoTime) == 0 % There is at least one entry without "HH:MM:SS PM"
        all_pos_without_time = find(IdxNoTime == 0);
        for i = 1:sum(IdxNoTime == 0)
            X{all_pos_without_time(i)} = [X{all_pos_without_time(i)},' 12:00:00 AM'];
        end
    end
    Y = datenum(X,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS PM');
    % datestr(ENTRYTIMENUM,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS PM'); % For checking

end
```

Can anyone see a prettier way to do it?

I'm thinking something along the lines of `X{ X[end]~='M' } += ' 12:00:00 AM';` but I can't see any way of accomplishing that with the syntax Matlab offers.

(Speed is not important here).

Comment: Can you clarify input and desired output? Anyway, `datenum` seems to be ok with time being missing, and assumes `12:00:00 AM`. Run `datenum({'5/1/2009 3:02:00 PM'; '5/1/2009'})` for example

Comment: What version of MATLAB was that code written to work with? I'm thinking this may have been a workaround for a prior version, since `datenum` appears to handle this just fine in current versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first using [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) to convert all the dates with the desired format `'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa'`, identifying dates that didn't convert using [`isnat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnat.html), then converting those with the shortened format `'dd/MM/yyyy'`. Then you can convert to a numeric value using [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html). I used the sample data from the help text of your function as input `X`:

```
% Input:
X = {'5/1/2009 3:02:00 PM'; ...
     '5/1/2009 4:11:00 PM'; ...
     '5/1/2009'; ...
     '6/1/2009 12:37:00 AM'; ...
     '7/1/2009 3:08:00 AM'; ...
     '7/1/2009 9:30:00 PM'};

% Conversion code:
Y = datetime(X, 'Format', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa');
index = isnat(Y);
Y(index) = datetime(X(index), 'Format', 'dd/MM/yyy');
Y = datenum(Y);
```

And to confirm the correct output:

```
>> datestr(Y)

ans =

05-Jan-2009 15:02:00
05-Jan-2009 16:11:00
05-Jan-2009 00:00:00  % Notice it has assumed 12:00:00 AM
06-Jan-2009 00:37:00
07-Jan-2009 03:08:00
07-Jan-2009 21:30:00
```

Comment: Unfortunately this assumes the rather stupid MM/DD/YYYY format -- my data is in DD/MM/YYYY format. If I specify `datenum( colEntryTime_TEXT, 'dd/mm/yyyy  HH:MM:SS PM' )` it now fails for entries without a specified time.